# I don't understand these Tracert hops

Tags: routes

We have an application running on a remote mySQL connection and a user complained that his connection was slow. The connection speed has since improved but I would like to understand this routing.

He is using a 4G Router and that might be relevant from search results elsewhere.

The default gateway on the router is 192.168.2.1

1 192.168.2.1

2 MIKE-PC [192.168.225.1]

3 192.168.213.21

4 192.168.213.22

5 Request timed out

6 Request timed out

7 63.130.104.194

... all OK to the database server from here

He uses a wired connection (dynamic ip) in office and assures me that the wireless adapter is disabled (switch on notebook). Whilst all works as I would expect from a tracert at his home using the wireless adapter. I have tried to ascertain the ip address in both instances but the user isn't IT savvy.

Regards, Ian

Answer (score 0):

These are the hosts between your computer (where you had run tracert) an the target computer.
Several of them are configured to not respond to any icmp packets (5 and 6).

Comment: Apologies and thank you for your input but (I'd like to be able to form the perfect question) but that is not what I find a mystery. I would expect to see (in the example above)

1 192.168.2.1

2 Request timed out

3 Request timed out

4 63.130.104.194

I do not understand why the route is bouncing around on private addresses first.

Regards, Ian

Comment: Check to see routing table on 192.168.2.1 maybe there is a static route there.
If you perform let's say: "tracert 193.226.58.1" check to see on 192.168.2.1 if there is a static route to 193.1226.58.0/24 with MIKE-PC as gateway.

Comment: Many thanks. I will be visiting this site in a couple of weeks or so, I will post my findings here.

Regards, Ian

Comment: Most welcome!
If you find my answer useful, then you can check the check mark below the answer to validate as the answer :)